# Convert curl to c# code using HttpClient

Tags: javascript, c#, curl

I would like to send curl request that I got from JS code below with HttpClient.

```
curl -v -X GET "hxxps://airport.api.aero/airport?user_key=[token]"
```

so I wrote the C# code

```
string response = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("hxxps://airport.api.aero/airport?user_key=[token]"));
```

and I tried to deserialize the response with the code below.

```
// deserialize the JSON object response, the information will become an AirportObject.RootObject instance
rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AirportObject.RootObject>(response);
```

rootObject is an instance of C# class object and the information received from the link is in JSON format. Therefore, it needs a conversion from JSON to an instance of C# class.

Also, when I tried to visit the link directly, it gave the JSON data encapsulated with callback() function.

Did I write it correct?
When I run it, it did nothing.

Thanks.

[FIXED]
so my problem was just not specifying the headers type. Here is the code fixing the program:

```
//set request headers to accept JSON data
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Comment: `it did nothing.` No need to give that much info to us. We like to guess the problems.....

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to get a response to deserialize it:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/api/v1/");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("some");

if(response.IsSuccessfulStatusCode)
{
     // The entity is within the response's content
     RootObject root = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootObject>();
}
```

Comment: sorry I did not mentioned it. RootObject is actually an instance of C# class object. I need to deserialize the information obtained from the link in which the format is in JSON, to rootobject.
Also, I am confused because when I visited the link directly from the browser, it gives the JSON data encapsulated with callback() function